# How to perform a distribution upgrade using apt-fast?

Tags: upgrade, release-management

My distribution upgrade from natty to ocelot has been running on and off for quite some time. The speeds at which it downloads is really slow, and I was wondering if there was a way to use the `apt-fast` command to perform a distribution upgrade to ocelot ?

I looked into the source of `do-release-upgrade` but it uses the Upgrade module in python, and I could not find a reference to `apt-get` or `wget` which I could have replaced with `apt-fast` or `axel`.

Maybe if I could just perform an update via `do-release-upgrade` and then run `apt-fast upgrade` when it asks me to press ENTER after updating the software sources ? Would it work ?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? Your question was just allocated to me as part of [Clean-Up](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/2863/its-time-for-clean-up-week).

Comment: Yes, I tried the above and it does work. I'll write down an answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I tried it out, and it does work.

A`do-release-upgrade` would update your software sources to point to the newer version of ubuntu. After it runs an update, and asks you to press enter to start the process of upgrade, just *open a new terminal*, and start the upgrade yourself.

You'd need to delete the lock file for apt first.

```
sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/lock
apt-fast dist-upgrade
```

Remember that this has to be entered on a new terminal, because, if you cancel the upgrade at that step, the upgrade rolls back the changes to the repositories.

After `apt-fast` finishes, you can shift to the original terminal and continue the upgrade

Comment: I guess it works only for normal dist upgrade but not for beta/dev dist upgrade.