# Is it still possible to do distribution upgrade using apt-fast?

Tags: apt, upgrade

Over the past several upgrades, I've used the method in this thread: [How to perform a distribution upgrade using apt-fast?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/54419/how-to-perform-a-distribution-upgrade-using-apt-fast?rq=1)

However, when I've tried to use this method to upgrade to Wily Werewolf apt-fast dist-upgrade doesn't find any files.  Is there a new method?